# How can I get an error msg from the lightning-file-upload component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

How can I extract an error msg from the lightning-file-upload component when it gets a wrong file format? I'd like to catch it and show in a different place.

```
<lightning-file-upload
name="fileUploader"
accept={allowedFileExtensions}
record-id={recordId}
onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
multiple>
</lightning-file-upload>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, there is no property or public method that allows you to interact with the error state of the component. or at leas this is what the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation) seems to indicate. in order to fully customize the behavior of a component when uploading documents, you would have to build your own component.